# Edittext unable to receive input from keyboard while in dialog box for above android N

Tags: java, android, android-xml, android-dialog

I'm setting up a dialog to get the pin number from the user. While the dialog does appear with the keyboard but edittext receive no input from keyboard. The same dialog box work on the android 6. Below is the code

Code for dialog

```
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View promptsView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_password,
            null);
    Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getApplicationContext()
            , android.R.style.Theme_Black_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
    dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    dialog.setCancelable(false);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        dialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY);
    }
    else {
        dialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE);
    }
    dialog.getWindow().setLayout(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    dialog.setContentView(promptsView);
    dialog.getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    dialog.show();
```

XML Layout Code:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:text="Enter Your Pin"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        />
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:hint="Enter Pin"
        android:id="@+id/enter_pin"
        android:inputType="numberPassword"
        android:textAlignment="center"

        />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/confirm"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/enter_pin"
        android:text="Confirm"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code for in Java file for dialog:

```
                Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
                dialog.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.activity_password);
                dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
                dialog.getWindow().setLayout(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                Window window = dialog.getWindow();
                window.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                dialog.show();
```

This code worked into above android N and as well as in below android N.

I hope its work for you.